# SCSS dynamic color changing

Tags: css, colors, sass

I just started using SCSS and I've been having some problems on dynamically changing the color of my website. What I want to do is create a list of colors and every time I refresh the page, it changes the color selected. Here is the code:

SCSS:

```
$colors: (
      #cc6698,
      #0869ad,
      #ff8300,
      #7A86b8,
      #f05133,
      #2aa9e0,
      #71bf45,
      #ef0e39,
      #9e79d7,
    );

    $color: nth($colors, random(length($colors)));
```

However, it changes the color only when I modify the file, not on every page refresh. What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: I think you'd need javascript for that.

Comment: Where do you compile your SCSS files?

Comment: What I do is: "sass watch custom.css:custom.scss --style compressed"

Comment: It will not work because you compile your SCSS file and it generates CSS file. Then when you refresh the page new CSS file will NOT be created. One way is to take the approach I posted.

Comment: @GusFulton You understand that Sass only compiles to CSS, right?  What you're asking for requires the browser itself to understand Sass.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, but you have to compile your SCSS files (using [sass.js](https://github.com/medialize/sass.js/)) in the browser to see the effect.

HTML:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor maiores placeat illo culpa quam, magnam sunt accusantium enim dicta temporibus, reiciendis soluta iure, reprehenderit qui vel perspiciatis suscipit earum asperiores.</p>
```

SASS:

```
$colors: (
  #cc6698,
  #0869ad,
  #ff8300,
  #7A86b8,
  #f05133,
  #2aa9e0,
  #71bf45,
  #ef0e39,
  #9e79d7,
);

$color: nth($colors, random(length($colors)));

body {
  color: $color;
}
```

Check this (to see the effect add text to paragraph or refresh the page):

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOdojx)

Comment: I do the exactly same thing. I compile in the terminal using : "sass watch custom.css:custom.scss --style compressed" but still not changing.

Comment: Check my comment below your post.

Comment: How do I compile files with sass.js though?

Comment: Codepen doesn't use sass.js.  It compiles it on the server each time you request the page or modify your code, and then serves the compiled CSS.

Comment: I know that, I am not an expert with that, but I think you can somehow recieve similar result to Codepen using sass.js (not on each request, but on refresh).

Comment: How would you do it then cimmanon? I want to change the color every refresh and not every time I compile.